# Google Advertising ID equivalent for Amazon devices

Tags: android, kindle-fire, kindle

Wondering whats equivalent for Google Advertising Id for Amazon kindle/phone devices?

I researched around, and it seems only "Secure.ANDROID_ID" seems to be nearest solution. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I do am encountering the same scenario. I have an app that is currently listed on Google Play that I would like to post on the Amazon Appstore as well but it currently uses the advertising identifier that is provided by Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find anything equivalent for now but i was able to install Google aps on my kindle fire HD 6 and managed to have an Google Advertising ID.

In order to do that you need File explorer application on Kindle to install Google aps. Go on this url with amazon device: http://www.amazon.co.uk/ES-Mobile-File-Explorer/dp/B008K6HN8I and install the application

You will need to install basics Google Application to make things works. 4 Apps are needed to enable Google account on Amazon devices:

- Google Account Manager
- Google Services
- Google framework
- Google PlayStore

You can find the apk online, here for example: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=73036323a69e3cf1&id=73036323A69E3CF1%211484&authkey=%21AIVXLFXAOWDeM0Q

Transfer Google aps on Kindle fire if you didn't download them directly on it.
In order to install them, you need to first enable Unknown Sources. To do that go to Settings> Applications, tap On for Apps from Unknown Sources.
Then launch file explorer and go to the folder you transfer or download google aps and install them in this order :

1. Google Account Manager
2. Google Services
3. Google framework
4. Google PlayStore

Then launch Google Play Store, it will ask you for a Google account and you will have a Google Advertising ID. For now, i wasn't able to found it.

I hope this can help you !

Comment: I'm pretty sure users of the app won't be happy with these extra steps. I'm looking for built-in way for Amazon platform.

Comment: Yes, i agree, but atm it's the only way i found to have a Google ID on Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the `Fire OS 5.1` you can use the `advertising_id` string

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tablets/app-development/using-the-advertising-id-in-your-app

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/18194/using-the-advertising-id-in-your-app.html